# 2010 Access vba setting filter on Excel date column

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, autofilter

I have a 2010 Access vba module that clears the filters on a worksheet and then sets a new filter.  I use code like this in another module that works fine.  This code is not working and I wonder if it's because the column is formatted as a date.

```
With wksReportingAccountBalance
    .Activate
    .Select
    .Unprotect
End With
On Error Resume Next
    XL.Selection.AutoFilter

... do some work on the sheet

With wksReportingAccountBalance
    .Activate
' filter field is column "M"
    .Range("$A:$R").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=StrToday
    .Protect
End With
```

The code that works in the other module is:

```
wksModelsModels.Activate
On Error Resume Next
    XL.Selection.AutoFilter

... do some work on the sheet

With wksModelsModels
    .Activate
    .Range("$A:$O").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=SearchCriterial
End With
```

Field 11 in wksModelsModels is a string/text field.  Field 13 in wksReportingAccountBalance is a ShortDate field.

What seems to be my problem?

Comment: What is the datatype & value assigned to your variable `StrToday`?

Comment: It is a string.  I've also tried using a "Date" type variable. and I've tried ".Range("$A:$R").Columns(13).AutoFilter 3, 4, 11".  None of the three work.  The column is defined as "Date" in Excel.

Comment: After a lot of trial and error, I have come to the conclusion that even if you copy an Excel column that was updated by Access through a "refresh", you cannot filter on it if it is a date (not sure if this is the only field type that doesn't work).

I was able to get this to work by copying the date from the "date" field to a new column using a formula (direct copy did not work).

    StrFormula = "=TEXT(M2," & Chr(34) & "m/d/yyyy" & Chr(34) & ")"
    sheet.range(T2) = StrFormula

Then I copied the formula down the column.

I then set the filter on this new column and it worked.